# Adding more layers with TensorFlow Error

Tags: tensorflow, mnist

I am trying to add more layers to my neural network in tensor flow, but here I am receiving this error.

```
ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 256 and 784 for 'MatMul_1' (op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [?,256], [784,256].
```

This is how I am creating the weights and the bias.

```
# Store layers weight & bias
weights = {
    'hidden_layer': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_hidden_layer])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_layer, n_classes]))
}
biases = {
    'hidden_layer': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_layer])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))
}
```

Here is where I am making my model

```
# Hidden layer with RELU activation
layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x_flat, weights['hidden_layer']), biases['hidden_layer'])
layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(layer_1)
layer_1 = tf.nn.dropout(layer_1, keep_prob)

layer_2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['hidden_layer']), biases['hidden_layer'])
layer_2 = tf.nn.relu(layer_2)
layer_2 = tf.nn.dropout(layer_2, keep_prob)
# Output layer with linear activation
logits = tf.matmul(layer_2, weights['out']) + biases['out']
```

And the error is most probably in layer_2. I am using the MNIST dataset. And also the x y, an xflat are reshaped to

```
x shape is  (?, 28, 28, 1)
y shape is  (?, 10)
x flat shape is  (?, 784)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use different weights and biases for layer 1 and layer 2.

The problem is that both layer 1 and layer 2 are made for inputs of size 784. But layer 1 has outputs of size 256, so layer 2 can't work with that.

Specifically the matrices `layer_1` and `weights['hidden_layer']` that you try to multiply in this line have incompatible sizes:

```
layer_2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['hidden_layer']), biases['hidden_layer'])
```

This might work instead:

```
# Store layers weight & bias
weights = {
    'layer_1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_hidden_layer])),
    'layer_2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_layer, n_hidden_layer])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_layer, n_classes]))
}
biases = {
    'layer_1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_layer])),
    'layer_2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_layer])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))
}
```

and

```
# Hidden layer with RELU activation
layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x_flat, weights['layer_1']), biases['layer_1'])
layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(layer_1)
layer_1 = tf.nn.dropout(layer_1, keep_prob)

layer_2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['layer_2']), biases['layer_2'])
layer_2 = tf.nn.relu(layer_2)
layer_2 = tf.nn.dropout(layer_2, keep_prob)
# Output layer with linear activation
logits = tf.matmul(layer_2, weights['out']) + biases['out']
```

Comment: Yes ofcourse, that was such a simpleee thingg,,, I totally forgot that I was using the same weights and bias. Thanks a-lot, I was stressing for an hour and totally ignored that. 
Thank you.